# UserVoice get all tickets v2

Tags: c#, uservoice

How can I get all the tickets in UserVoice version 2 with the C# wrapper classes? I have gotten them in v1 with the API call

```
var response = client.Get("/api/v1/tickets.json");
```

[v1 link to the call.](https://developer.uservoice.com/docs/api/reference/#_api_v1_tickets_get)

How is it possible to do this in v2? I have tried using their `Message`, `MessageResponse`, `SuggestionActivityEntryResponse`, and `Ticket` classes as well as making calls on the client variable like in v1.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the v2 API does not currently support it, you should generally fall back to the v1 API as v2 is a Beta.